# Can I post self-answers that do not contain any code?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I know that I can make questions on Stack Overflow that already have the answer, by myself. But if I want to post a personal solution method for a problem (which is not necessarily the best/fastest way to do it, but may help for someone), without any kind of codes, am I allowed to do it?

Comment: If your solution has specific applications in which it is better than the existing answers or is easier to implement then I don't see why not. If it’s neither of these things then why bother?

Comment: I asked it specifically because of the solutions instead of codes, because most of the helpful answers I've seen on SO contain some kind of codes.

Comment: Let's put it like this: if your answer would be just fine if you were not answering your own question, it's fine when you are. There are no special rules or exceptions for self-answered questions and answers.

Comment: @Zoltán do you have an example of a particular answer that you're not sure about?

Comment: @KyleStrand of course: something [like this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48127/how-can-i-have-multiple-layers-in-my-map-array/56000#56000) but with less or even without codes.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt That answer actually has quite a bit of code in it...anything more than that is likely to be more annoying than useful (in my opinion, at least). Questions and answers without code are not uncommon; see, for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/q/761194/1858225

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... yes, provided:

- Your question is good enough to stand on its own
- Your answer addresses the question entirely and correctly

then I don't see any particular reason why code is *necessary*, but it would certainly be unusual not to include some. Depends on the question, of course.