# What should I do if I find the answer to my question before someone else answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

[Kinda related to my previous question:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181415/can-i-post-self-answers-that-do-not-contain-any-code) sometimes there happens that I post question before I think the problem over well enough. (if I know well it's not against the rules, the only problem with it is that it gets a lot of downvotes if noticed) If I got the solution before anyone would help, what to do. Should I delete the question, or keeping it with an own answer for the site would be worth?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about -- *"We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers"*. So as soon as you ask the question, it should already be good enough to help a future visitor too. And questions need answers.

Comment: @Arjan As I mention to Bart below, I just afraided that those questions which anwers can be found for so quickly are either too localized or not helpful enough.

Comment: You will have to evaluate that on a case-by-case basis. You certainly can't make the general statement that a question/answer will not be useful just because it is "easy". It might be too localized or not helpful to others; in that case, you should delete it. But don't make that decision lightly. If it was a good enough question for you to ask on the site, it's good enough to have asked *and answered*.

Comment: Of course I know that easy question != bad question. I try to think over while posting a question that how people will be able to use it as a solution for their own problems. I decide about usefulness this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is a good one (and the solution has not changed that), deleting it because you found the answer will in no way benefit the site. Add your own answer.

Solving your own problem is by no means a bad thing. And you might help others in the process. Heck, we even have [the explicit ability to post self-answered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz).

Comment: Well, yes, you are right. I may not lose anything. 

I just afraided that those questions which anwers can be found for so quickly are either too localized or not helpful enough.

Comment: Then indeed delete, @Zoltán, but next time don't ask such question then. Beware that deleting too many question might get you banned.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt That's what you might have to evaluate. Is the question a good one. If it isn't, then deleting might be an option. But having found the answer yourself doesn't really change that situation. If it's a decent question, just post the answer.

Comment: @Arjan Deleting my own question would get me banned? it's odd. Anyway, it doesn't happen often, I may have no more than 3 deleted ones in the last half year.

Comment: Not too odd, @Zoltán. If it was not worth keeping, one could say [you wasted people's time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029). And lowered the overall quality of the site while the question was not deleted yet.

Comment: But @Arjan with the fact that I deleted the question I approved its uselessness and tried to fix my mistake.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt What we know from the automatic ban mechanism is that it seems to interpret that as a negative thing. I.e. you deleted a question, therefore it must have been bad, therefore, if you do it too often, you get banned from asking questions. But that needs a relatively substantial amount of deletions. One single deleted question won't do it.

Comment: Thanks @Bart it makes more sense. I must approve this "logic".

Comment: I believe that it also takes the *score* of those deleted questions into account. The lower their score when they are deleted, the more likely you are to reach the ban threshold. @zol

Answer (score 2):

Especially if you have only a few questions, **don't delete bad ones**, make them better. This might mean adding a little detail before you answer.

Example original bad question:

> What wrong with my app it give excpetion when I try to run it?

This has bad grammar, no code, and no error message. Not surprisingly, no-one will answer it. An example this extreme would probably go on hold immediately, but that doesn't change this process much and a slightly less awful question would not be on hold.

So in parallel, you can improve your question (add code, add the actual error message, let others edit your grammar and spelling if you can't) and look in to the problem. Let's say you discover that it is an access denied error. Make sure you put that in the question right away.

Eventually you may solve your problem. Since you have now created a good question, that others could search for because it has the functions or frameworks you're using, along with the error message, it's worth answering. If you know the answer, answer it.